# Clang Dump AST of Python headers

Tags: python, c++, clang

I am using:
`clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/boolobject.h`

on the header to try to get all function declarations in a header

`boolobject.h`:

```
/* Boolean object interface */

#ifndef Py_BOOLOBJECT_H
#define Py_BOOLOBJECT_H
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


PyAPI_DATA(PyTypeObject) PyBool_Type;

#define PyBool_Check(x) Py_IS_TYPE(x, &PyBool_Type)

/* Py_False and Py_True are the only two bools in existence.
Don't forget to apply Py_INCREF() when returning either!!! */

/* Don't use these directly */
PyAPI_DATA(PyLongObject) _Py_FalseStruct;
PyAPI_DATA(PyLongObject) _Py_TrueStruct;

/* Use these macros */
#define Py_False ((PyObject *) &_Py_FalseStruct)
#define Py_True ((PyObject *) &_Py_TrueStruct)

// Test if an object is the True singleton, the same as "x is True" in Python.
PyAPI_FUNC(int) Py_IsTrue(PyObject *x);
#define Py_IsTrue(x) Py_Is((x), Py_True)

// Test if an object is the False singleton, the same as "x is False" in Python.
PyAPI_FUNC(int) Py_IsFalse(PyObject *x);
#define Py_IsFalse(x) Py_Is((x), Py_False)

/* Macros for returning Py_True or Py_False, respectively */
#define Py_RETURN_TRUE return Py_NewRef(Py_True)
#define Py_RETURN_FALSE return Py_NewRef(Py_False)

/* Function to return a bool from a C long */
PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyBool_FromLong(long);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif /* !Py_BOOLOBJECT_H */
```

But it gives me the following errors:

```
boolobject.h:10:26: error: expected function body after function declarator
PyAPI_DATA(PyTypeObject) PyBool_Type;
                         ^
boolobject.h:18:26: error: expected function body after function declarator
PyAPI_DATA(PyLongObject) _Py_FalseStruct;
                         ^
boolobject.h:19:26: error: expected function body after function declarator
PyAPI_DATA(PyLongObject) _Py_TrueStruct;
                         ^
boolobject.h:26:17: error: expected function body after function declarator
PyAPI_FUNC(int) Py_IsTrue(PyObject *x);
                ^
boolobject.h:30:17: error: expected function body after function declarator
PyAPI_FUNC(int) Py_IsFalse(PyObject *x);
                ^
boolobject.h:38:12: error: unknown type name 'PyObject'
PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyBool_FromLong(long);
           ^
boolobject.h:38:24: error: expected function body after function declarator
PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyBool_FromLong(long);
                       ^
```

I also tried to parse it with `libclang` in `python`:

```
import sys
from typing import List

import clang
import clang.cindex
from clang.cindex import *

def traverse(node):
    for child in node.get_children():
        traverse(child)
    print('Found %s [line=%s, col=%s] -- %s' % (node.displayname, node.location.line, node.location.column, node.kind))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    clang.cindex.Config.set_library_path('/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib')

    index = Index.create()
    args = ['-xc++', '--std=c++17']
    translation_unit = index.parse(
        "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/boolobject.h",
        args=args,
        options=TranslationUnit.PARSE_INCOMPLETE)
    print('Translation unit:', translation_unit.spelling)
    traverse(translation_unit.cursor)
```

But it doesn't parse everything. It only spits out `VAR_DECL`'s:

```
Found PyTypeObject [line=10, col=12] -- CursorKind.VAR_DECL
Found PyLongObject [line=18, col=12] -- CursorKind.VAR_DECL
Found PyLongObject [line=19, col=12] -- CursorKind.VAR_DECL
Found  [line=6, col=8] -- CursorKind.UNEXPOSED_DECL
```

Any ideas how to fix this, so that it can parse the header? Am I missing a flag somewhere either on the command-line or the above python code?

Comment: You would have to first include the header that defines what PyAPI_DATA means (and so on)

Comment: @user253751; Even if I do that: `clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only -I/include/python3.11 /include/python3.11/boolobject.h`, it still gives the error.

Comment: well yes, you would have to first include the header that defines what PyAPI_DATA means (and so on). Normally a C program would include some kind of python header and then this one. By including just this header by itself, all the python things aren't defined.

Comment: Ahh I made a C file that included the files and it parsed :)

Comment: If you solved the problem, why not answer your own question? Anyway, see [Python.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.2/Include/Python.h#L54). That boolobject.h is not included alone.

Comment: @relent95 there’s a time limit before I can give an answer myself. I will in a sec when it lets me.